# Crystal Reports Chart Color Highlights

Tags: visual-studio-2010, charts, crystal-reports

I am using the color highlights tab in the chart expert form in Crystal Reports in visual studio 2010.

The problem is that the equal to argument box is only accepting 4 characters. Does anyone know why this is?

[Picture Chart Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpACZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The Color Highlight gets it variable characteristics from the Datasource. Once I changed the variable to a larger length it changed the amount in the argument.